# Create a tag homepage/FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

Create or allow for a community-wiki editable home page per tag. One where we could place essentially the tag-specific FAQ and other tag-specific links.

<sub>[Imported from uservoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/138261-allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page)</sub>

Comment: Related: [Planning thread for per-tag FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50783/planning-thread-for-per-tag-faq)

Comment: I'd love it if the C tag had its own FAQ ...

Answer (score 14):

Further to Brad's - the most common dups, too (I haven't added links, but you get the idea):

- Frequent C# Questions

  - What are the correct version numbers ;-p
  - Parameter passing "by ref" vs "by type", and "value type" vs "reference type"
  - My `foreach` loop only sees the last value
  - When to use `this`
  - Why should I use properties?

Comment: Just came here searching for [faq] because I was so surprised to see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076965/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-a-destructor-and-a-finalize-method-in-a-clas is the first [c#][destructors] or [c#][finalize] question. That makes it the one to duplicate!

Comment: I've started a separate question as a suggested collection point for FAQ questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50783/suggestion-planning-thread-for-per-tag-faq feel free to add yours if you want.

Answer (score 11):

Edit.

**This is now done.**

Every tag has a tag info page, for example: [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=faq&sort=info&pagesize=50) if you have more than 100 upvotes on non-wiki answers with that tag you are entitled to edit the wiki section.

---

Since I just posted [PostType = Wiki, Wiki + Reputation can it be done?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49716/posttype-wiki-wiki-reputation-can-it-be-done) I would like to explain how I would see these features tie together.

When you click on a tag, it's really nice to have a list of questions in the sort order you choose. I do not feel a different look and feel for each tag home page would be a good idea. I also do not think that we should dictate sort orders or filtering to users.

However, I think we have enough space (6/8 lines) that can show up first (where the ad is now)  and presents common / highly voted, wiki topics on the tag.

So, for example, clicking on C# you would have a little box:

---

- Getting started with C#
- Common issues with C#
- Hidden feature of C#

---

Also I would make the tag front page Google indexable, so when people google `C#` Stack Overflow shows up first.

A very simple way to implement this would be to allow users with a gold badge in a tag to pin up to 6 questions to a tag.

Comment: Good idea. I can image these links getting a lot of page rank

Comment: Is there a revision history kept for these new info pages?

Comment: @Shog9 I store it in a table, but there is no UI yet

Comment: Fair enough. Nice work so far - plenty of room, no obvious constraints on content.

Comment: Besides the revision history we might need a mod-flag button there as well :)

Comment: @waffles: is there a meta question on this feature? Because I'd like to suggest you also add an RSS feed for tag wiki revisions.

Comment: @John, nope I do not think so

Comment: @waffles: actually, I found a question more or less about the feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

## You mean something like this:

---

## perl

---

### Related tags

- [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5)
- [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6)

### Outside links

- [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org)
- [perl.org](http://perl.org)

Answer (score 5):

*from uservoice*

I think that these types of pages would become stable fairly quickly, so a good FAQ could be compiled for all of the major tags. Also, if something controversial is added, then it needs to be stated as such or removed outright. Voting is probably the answer for dealing with this.

I also completely agree with Jon Skeet's idea (from user voice) of having a reputation barrier per tag. In other words, you must have earned 1000 reputation in `Java` tagged questions in order to contribute to that FAQ.

Comment: To be petty and pedantic, I made the same suggestion (limit per rep in that tag), earlier.

Comment: The list of comments for that suggestion was fairly long, I didn't read through the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

This request appears stagnant, yet I think it would be very useful. The issue just came up (well, I *helped* it come up): see comments at [How to force overriding a method in a descendant, without having an abstract base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118055/how-to-force-overriding-a-method-in-a-descendant-without-having-an-abstract-base/2118732#2118732).

If nobody can think of a *really* good reason to not do this, I think I might just get started.

I propose a CW "question" named "C# Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)" with "header" information, like related tags, index of other FAQ articles, etc. Then subsequent CW "questions" like "C# FAQ - Covariance and Contravariance in C# (Variance)".

Comment: Are you planning on doing it on Meta, or on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Brad: StackOverflow

Comment: This is a good idea. Why wait when we can demonstrate why this would be valuable. Have you started it yet?

Comment: @Casebash: no, I have not.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this to work, there would need to be an "authority" or an authoratative group and I don't think that can be managed within the current system. Possibly you could have moderator specific tags like we do on meta, but that would create a lot of overhead work for the moderators, and I'm certain there are tags where none of the moderators are experts and therefore wouldn't know what should be made part of the faq.

In the end, perhaps a feature where once a user has earned silver or gold in a tag would allow them to vote on adding/removing questions from that tags faq might work, but I think there's probably a lot of design that would have to go into it. But until some new feature is implemented to address, I believe current system cannot make this work well enough for it to be beneficial. Too many users are able to modify tags and/or edit questions and answers without need for "community support", and therefore, too often I think debates and/or edit wars would result.

Answer (score 2):

I started this already for Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839305/python-frequently-asked-questions). I don't know if this is what you had in mind, but I suppose starting is the only way for things to happen

Comment: I do hope you didn't mind it being closed very quickly. :-)

Comment: @Donal: I think it'll be reopened even quicker =P

Answer (score 2):

I'm totally in favour of this. There are some questions that pop up *all the time*, so often that marking them as dupes becomes really, really cumbersome. Also, it's hard to spot the "best" question among dozens when looking for dupes. We really need reference answers (covering all possibilities and edge cases) to some of those questions.