# A dictionary type feature (tag?) on Stack overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

We get many questions that ask the definition of a term. Now there was a very interesting debate in *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291226/what-is-an-sdk-c)* question. They wanted to know what an sdk was. Some said (including me at first) that they should just google easy questions like that. But other pointed out that "no question is too noobish" and that if we have simple questions asked here, google will link to them.

A dictionary feature would be nice, just to look through the definitions of term as an easy to find mechanism. I would suggestion a tag, something like "definition" or "dictionary"

Its just an idea/possibility, it would have to be established and questions tagged for upkeep. Let us discuss :D

EDIT: **[this how now been solved with tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq)**

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page

Comment: Sounds like a lot more work than it's worth, but I actually like the idea in theory.

Comment: @Ian: in the absence of a feature like this, how much time are you willing to devote to closing the duplicates of "what is an sdk"?

Comment: @John: That time is irrelevant, seeing as I'm just avoiding work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're finally coming to terms with the fact that no question is considered too noobish; I see a lot fewer of them with multiple close votes anymore.  That is a good thing.

To the topic at hand, though, I'm not opposed to using a tag like `[definition]` for this purpose, but it would almost certainly have to be added by an experienced SO user.  I can't conceive of a good system to get new users to do it.  Either way, I wouldn't go any further than a tag for a couple of reasons:

1. The site will propose similar, existing questions, which means that user #47 to ask what an SDK is will be shown the existing questions and (hopefully) the good, existing answers;
2. I think we should embrace the existing structure whenever possible to handle features like this, as opposed to tacking on yet another niche solution, complete with its own little-known behaviors and bugs.

Comment: I agree, I definitely don't think we need more than a tag. I mainly wanted to throw out the noob questions issue for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [noob]  tag? I often browse questions about things I'm pretty new to, because it's a good way to learn stuff. For the stuff I'm a noob in it would be good to be able to focus on the noob questions.

After all we're all noobs in something.

Comment: We do have [beginner].