# official list of common questions/answers for dupes

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If there isn't already one I just missed, can we start some kind of "official list" of common questions and answers? For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296892/c-interface-implementation-and-generic-collections-question) has been asked a gazillion times [literally :)] but I don't know of (or if there is) one really solid, authoritative Skeet-like question/answer we can always point back to.

It'd be nice to have some central list for those kinds of common topics.

**Edit:** To clarify, this would not be for normal end-users. Obviously they couldn't manage to find any of the duplicates, so I don't expect them to look at this list either. I have in mind a list for mods and pseudo-mods like myself, so when I see a question I know is a dupe many times over, I don't have to go hunting for the best question - I can just check the list which *we* maintain.

Comment: How would this list be maintained?

Comment: @jjnguy on a post here.

Comment: How many is a gazillion, exactly? I want to support your suggestion, but can't without first verifying that your figures are accurate.

Comment: @Shog9 more than one, but less than infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Back in the "uservoice" days, I proposed this in the context of having a tag-specific home page, editable by users with enough rep (perhaps in that tag, perhaps just "some value"). Similar to "stats", but user content. This would be useful for common dups in an area.

Edit: found it: [Allow a per-tag home/FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page) ;-p

However, without trying it, I don't know whether this would be a help or a burden...

Comment: Like some kind of tag wiki info page

Comment: @random wow, Aug '09. That feels long, long, long ago now

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that would be very helpful. If someone isn't going to take the time to search SO thoroughly before asking a question, they probably aren't going to read through a long list of questions either (if they can even find *that* on the site).

...and I doubt it will be helpful to closers wanting to link to duplicates, because they can probably find the duplicates quickly anyway.

Comment: +1 anyone who bothers to look for and read such a list isn't the sort of person who will post a common dupe.

Answer (score 2):

FAQs / lists of FAQs are great, if someone is willing and able to maintain them. I say "someone", because otherwise they tend to either grow into AAQs or wither away and die.

So... If you want to start it and maintain it, i'll... up-vote it and probably use it.