# Request to reopen SO question on JavaScript error detection

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

Here is the question:

[How can I check JavaScript code for syntax errors ONLY from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856097/how-can-i-check-javascript-code-for-syntax-errors-only-from-the-command-line)

Several days ago I cast a reopen vote.

I've edited the question to the best of my ability so that it fits in the SO scope. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Sorry but looks like it still falls under "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource". While it might be helpful, those are simply off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'm not looking for any more tool recommendations than is the question [How to check if perl script doesn't have any compilation errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908416/how-to-check-if-perl-script-doesnt-have-any-compilation-errors). It's exactly the same kind of problem.

Comment: Well, there's no trivial way so it means you have to write your own command line application - or find existing application. Perl appears to come with its own command line tools.

Comment: I was hoping that maybe there's some command line option combination for an existing tool and I'm just missing something, because a lot of language compilers and interpreters have an option to check for syntax errors.

Comment: Specific problems that require tools to solve them are rather different from bald *requests for recommendations*, @Shadow.

Comment: Just noticed (randomly, because someone commented on it) that the question is no longer on hold. Is there no notification about the process of asking for reopening?

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is fine; I initially thought it was a duplicate, but searching has turned up only partial matches (folks looking to disable specific warnings) - so if it hasn't already been answered, I don't see any reason to close it.

And yeah, I also tire of the preachiness of (default rules) JSLint at times.

Comment: It's "tool recommendations" that are discouraged, @Ros - not "recommendations and questions *about* tools". Because the latter, strictly interpreted, would make off-topic just about every question on the site...