# Set of exact duplicates on getting the (x, y) coordinates of the caret in the textarea

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Original question, Aug 2008: [How do I get the (x, y) pixel coordinates of the caret in text boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes)

Exact duplicates:

1. [Display DIV at Cursor Position in Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128342/display-div-at-cursor-position-in-textarea) (Sep 2008)
2. [Textarea X/Y caret coordinates - jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510009/textarea-x-y-caret-coordinates-jquery-plugin/) (2010)
3. [How can I find the cursor location (X/Y, not line/column) in an HTML textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953037/how-can-i-find-the-cursor-location-x-y-not-line-column-in-an-html-textarea) (Aug 2011)
4. [Find caret position in textarea in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012835/find-caret-position-in-textarea-in-pixels) (Jan 2012)
5. [How to find pageX-pageY positions of the cursor (when inside a textbox) using javascript / jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185426/how-to-find-pagex-pagey-positions-of-the-cursor-when-inside-a-textbox-using-ja) (Aug 2012; currently has an inexact duplicate selected)
6. [Float a div on a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927258/float-a-div-on-a-textarea/22463060) (Oct 2012)
7. [Get the offset position of the caret in a textarea in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212871/get-the-offset-position-of-the-caret-in-a-textarea-in-pixels) (Apr 2013)

**UPDATE** After 5 quick downvotes and two close votes on this question itself (!) which have lead to it being put on hold (!!), perhaps I should clarify and state the obvious: I believe questions 1-7 should be speed-closed as duplicates.

I've tried going the official route (using my close votes), but they expired by the time anyone else had voted. [Here's my experience with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082921/get-caret-xy-coordinates-in-text-area).

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to achieve posting this here? Do you have a proposal to improve duplicate finding, asking for confirmation that you were correct in identifying the dupes, wanting us to vote to close the dupes?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: sorry if that was not obvious. I see there's an `exact-duplicates` tag, so I assume requests to close exact duplicates are common on MSO.

Comment: No, they are not; that's what we have a close vote review queue for. Meta is only needed for things that are not already handled by pre-existing features.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is a bad idea, but chat rooms might work better for it.

Comment: E.g. just vote to close as dupes, and let the CV review voters do the rest. Soliciting help in chat rooms is also more commonplace.

Comment: @Pëkka: I know we had that big bad backlog, but isn't that being beaten down with a vengeance now? This is not a big re-tagging job or anything, I don't think we need a close-vote rallying cry just yet.

Comment: So... five downvotes are how Meta rewards the work of finding duplicates, and pointing out a good original? Seriously?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've tried using my close votes, but they expired. [Here's my experience with that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082921/get-caret-xy-coordinates-in-text-area). The pre-existing feature doesn't always work as it should.

Comment: @Martijn to my knowledge, what was changed was the *number* displayed in the backlog - it was limited to showing questions with 4 close votes already so people don't get depressed. The *overall* queue is still gigantic as far as I know.

Comment: @Pëkka: Yes, I know, but the close vote *velocity* has gone up since we did that. The big bad backlog is shrinking now, no longer growing.

Comment: @Martijn but that means your dupe vote will be successful in 2019 instead of 2021. (I exaggerate, but you see my point.) I still don't think there's anything  wrong with coordinated efforts to close a certain group of questions.

Comment: @Pëkka: Perhaps, but I agree with your answer below that that's best left to the chat rooms, where you'll be more likely to find people with tag-specific knowledge. The Python chat room is quite active in keeping the tag clean. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The velocity has almost gone back to normal.  On the last chart [shog updated today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208311/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue) you can see more questions are being added than removed.  It doesn't appear that way because the queue only shows questions with 2+ votes or flags.  There's another 70k "hidden" review items.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your effort, it is appreciated.

Some Google queries are full of duplicate results where somebody should look for the best one, and a group effort could and should be made to close all of them swiftly.

Casting a close vote is nice and never the wrong thing to do, but the lack of direct feedback and the giant backlog take the fun out of that.

Unfortunately, there is no codified approach to coordinate such efforts. As you can see, Meta posts don't seem to be the right format. The per-tag chat rooms may be a better venue - the [PHP chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), for example, is very avid in garnering closevotes, and even has its own [closevote request monitoring system.](http://php.cv-pls.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I've just tried the PHP chatroom and got 2 quick close votes, then... nothing for another one of the questions :) Guess close fatigue was reached.

Comment: Give it time! I think their backlog works well generally (but things may have changed of course.)

Comment: @Dan Maybe also try meta again after the MSO/MSE split in 6-8 weeks.