# Can we get a shorthand link [metavotesfaq]?

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

The other day I discovered that we have [all sorts of really neat shorthand links we can use in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)!

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few
>   shorthand links are available.
>
> *italic* and **bold** text, inline `code in backticks`, and [basic links](http://example.com). Supported shorthand links:
>
> [meta] – link to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name
>   (e.g. "Super User Meta"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or
>   already is) a Meta site.
>
> [main] – like [meta], just the other way around.
>
> [edit] – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e.
>   /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).
>
> [...]
>
> [ask], [answer] – link to the How to Ask or How to Answer page.

With so many people complaining about / asking why they were downvoted on meta, I request a new comment shorthand link:

`[metavotefaq]` – link to [the faq section `vote-differences`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Link text is "Voting here works a bit differently from other Stack Exchange sites."

This way, we can easily comment to someone asking "Why was I downvoted?":

```
Because [metavotefaq]
```

Comment: Yes please! -----

Comment: And I'd *love* to see some generic comment macros as well, like a polite official version of "please don't just post a link to a web site that doesn't work; please post some code here" - I know there are browser extensions that can do this, but it would be nice to have those built in. But that is a different request, I guess.

Comment: Oooooh great idea @Pekka -- If you post that as a question in and of itself please link me and I will upvote!

Comment: will do, although I *think* that has been requested and declined before - I'll search for it later

Comment: This: [META-FAQ#vote-differences] `[META-FAQ#vote-differences]`

Comment: I wonder, would it be just as helpful to have an [s.tk](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dHZLQjdhWjdyRGRub21TTjNMOXo2Mnc6MQ&ndplr=1) link too/instead?

Answer (score 8):

You mean like `[meta-faq#vote-differences]`? This will generate a quick link to the FAQ section on meta votes being different. You could leave a comment like this:

> Votes on Meta are a bit different - they indicate disagreement, not necessarily that you are wrong. See the `[META-FAQ#vote-differences]` for more details.

This wouldn't insert the whole "votes are different" text, just the link. You could combine this with the [Proforma Comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) script from StackApps though:

> This script adds a little 'auto' link next to all comments boxes. When you click the link, you see a popup with 6 configurable auto-comments, which you can easily click to insert.
>
> [image]

The tool lets you save custom pre-formed comments. You could write a standard response to "why was I downvoted" which includes the short link mentioned above.

Comment: In accordance with [meta-faq#vote-differences] I am upvoting this answer due to the freehand circle within. (Okay, I'm really just testing your advice)

Comment: Awesome, that works well. Thanks! I'll probably opt for the Proforma script though because 1. Benjol is awesome and 2. As you said, this just generates a link saying **faq**. Also, I'm probably going to have a difficult time remembering the shortcut `[meta-faq#vote-differences]`

Comment: @TheUnhandledException you didn't vote me up for freehand circles? Aw... now I'm sad. What if I put in a pony?