# Should we build up the wiki aspect of SO by adding in QnA topics?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, community-wiki

Lots of uncopyrighted websites on the internet, typically built by Microsoft MVPs or the like, contain hundreds of common or complex questions, and solutions to those problems + code.

Should these be added into SO, like I did for [intro to TinyPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387400/what-is-tinypg-and-how-does-it-work)?

I thought this could build up the "wiki" aspect of SO where devs can simply search for their problem using the internal search *instead* of Google, and find answers quickly. This would probably limit the general problems or spammy "givemethecodez" Qs that newcomers post.

Comment: I don't think anyone seriously uses internal search instead of google unless you want special functionality (e.g tags, user searches).  Instead, use google with `site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page

Comment: Nothing is "uncopyrighted", especially nothing by Microsoft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to build up the wiki aspect of SO, then make the answer wiki so that more people can add to your answer (the threshold for editing wiki responses is lower).  You'll still gain reputation when people upvote the question, but it looks less like rep-whoring to those people who frown on posting questions that you know the answer to (I'm not in that group, I'm just saying).

Another thing I would stress is that you should always link to the original source of the information if you can.  Link to the web site or blog if that's where the information came from.  Link to amazon.com, or the author or publisher's web site if the information came from a book.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure these websites are "uncopyrighted"? Copyright is automatic in most jurisdictions.

I don't think there is any need to seed StackOverflow with content. Let it grow organically according to need.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the number of upvotes you've got, I think we should hold it for a while.

The wiki aspect of SO is constantly enforced when we edit others question/answers ( Just ask Rich B )