# Could SO sponsor the FAQ tag on Meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sponsored-tags

If you go to the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag here in Meta, you are greeted with the complete list of the [*sofaq overhaul project*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-question-how-do-they-work).

It occurred to me that the team could make the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag a sponsored one here on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), so it could have on the tag page (in addition to the image, if any - I don't know if it should even have one) a [list of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), [about pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) and maybe [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

[image]

Comment: Needs more aphids and deuterium.

Comment: But then they can't get paid sponsorship from http://www.faqs.org/

Comment: @rlb.usa - I don't think that was done in mspaint seeing as that doesn't look like it was screenshotted on a Windows system

Comment: @far, @rlb: GIMP FTW!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How much does it cost? Should we take venture capital to afford it?

edit: we now have a **house sidebar ad on the meta home page**. I don't think we want to extend this to *every* page that the sidebar appears on, though.

http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/9745/metahousead.png

As for the rest of your proposal, I am folding it into [Create a tag homepage/FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq) because I think that would be a way for the *community* to set up those editorial content tag-specific pages rather than us.

So transfer the "but it needs to be on the tag page!" votes to the above link.

Comment: I'm sure I can hook you up with discounted space for a small finders-fee...

Comment: For that info, email team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Might have some type of pay-as-you-go plan. I dunno.