# The "Case of the mondays?" ad should only run on Mondays

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I don't know why some people find this ad so annoying, but I love it. Mostly because Office Space is such a good movie and because I'm really irritable on Mondays and it makes me chuckle. I think it would be even funnier, though, if the ad only appeared on Mondays. Perhaps that would silence the haters just a little bit, as well. When I see "Case of the mondays?" on, say, Wednesday, it's just not as amusing as I wish it was.

Maybe on other days of the week, the StackOverflow Careers ad could be a picture of Milton with the caption "I told Bill that if they move my desk one more time, then, then I'm, I'm quitting" or something. That's a fairly weekday-independent advertisement, I would say.

Comment: I submit that it should only run on Henderday. Henderday is not a real day. I just made it up. This means that it would never run, and I would never have to see this annoying ad ever again.

Comment: +1 for the Milton suggestion.

Comment: I personally want to put my fist through my monitor whenever I see that add....

Comment: @snicker +1 this ad started creeping me out after the umpteenth time I saw it

Comment: @evan: I'm surprised you made it through umpteen viewings before it creeped you out.

Comment: Where can I see this horrible advert? I would like to join in the hatred.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting [feature-request] in the sense that you are requesting something that is not controlled by SO, and is fact a fact of the relationship between StackOverflow and their advertisers.

StackOverflow offers advertising space structured at a rate in a contract they define, and it is ultimately upt to the advertisers as to what they are doing with the space (after they have created an advertisement which the StackOverflow team has signed-off on).

So ultimately, you are asking for a feature of the advertising code be modified to allow time-sensitive ads (first thing in the morning, first day of the week, last day of the week, etc.) which is something that I would expect the advertisers to want, and not something that the community would have that large of an opinion about.

In general, I feel that this generalized feature will not be implemented unless StackOverflow wants to increase ad revenues, and the advertisers themselves have indicated that this is something they require.

Comment: StackOverflow Careers, which the ad is promoting, is from the same group that created StackOverflow (correct me if I'm wrong). If it were an ad for ReSharper, I would have sent this suggestion to JetBrains instead. It's a silly suggestion and I don't really expect anything to be done about it. But I can try, right? Also, as I said in another comment, I was under the impression date-based campaigns were a common feature in advertising systems and thus would already be available. If not, I suppose you could ultimately consider this a suggestion for date-based campaigns.

Comment: Ah, well, that makes me look a little bit foolish, although it does highlight the point that they'll only implement such a scheme if the advertizing clients want it. In this case the client is themselves, so I'll bet that they were able to reach an agreement *without* the date-based campaigns.

Comment: @devinb: may be [they can afford](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43703/could-so-sponsor-the-faq-tag-on-meta/43738#43738)  to strong arm the *SO Advertising Co.* ® now that they have venture capital money.

Comment: @perbert, do you think Jeff will take himself on like Norton in Fight Club?

Comment: @devinb: I'd pay to see that.

Comment: Now that I think about that, anyone knows what did they do to get the money in the first place? There must be footage some place!