# Should we create a section for less experienced programmers to ask "easy" questions?

Tags: discussion, new-users, question-difficulty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Propose Newbie-Overflow site or section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/propose-newbie-overflow-site-or-section)

Stack Overflow might consider setting up a section for less experienced programmers who ask what appear to be foolish questions to those more experienced.  I know at least two newbies who don't use the site after getting negative votes for questions they framed as carefully as possible.  Otherwise, this is a great resource.

Comment: There is *absolutely nothing* wrong with inexperienced programmers posting "simple" questions on this site. We certainly don't need a *new* site for something that is already perfectly acceptable on the *existing* site.

Comment: Can you show an example of such a question?

Comment: @Eat more Twisters  My question "Xcode not recognizing file" is an example of a newbie trying to ask an intelligent question.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573682/xcode-not-recognizing-file)? And why does that need to be posted on a separate site? The title isn't particularly clear and could be improved, but that would still be true even on a "Newbie Overflow" site.

Comment: @Cody Gray.  Understand.  I'll work to improve my questions.

Comment: Also don't take a single downvote too seriously. They happen to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think it's a good idea to do so, since a great thing in this site is that the quality of the question is what matters, not how advanced is it.. I think newbie questions here can be a good reference for the next newbies to come by... **BUT** a common thing happening here: newbies get downvotes, answers like `you should do your homework` or `should google it` and that's too much pressure on the newbie that is already in a great pressure learning new thing and trying not to give up... I think the real request to be made here is to **STOP THIS...**

Comment: Your suggestion "STOP THIS..." is right on. I don't think we need a new site, just a section that's a little more forgiving of newbies.  I already got a negative vote just for posting this suggestion.  That's not constructive.

Comment: The rule to "stop this" is basically already in effect. When you see rude comments like this, just flag them. They're not helping anyone and don't serve any purpose. A question that is legitimately bad and unhelpful should be closed, not mocked. The only exception is the rare comment when someone suggests to edit a question to show what you've already tried to solve the problem, making it seem less like you're just asking for someone else to do your homework for you.

Comment: The problem I see is that it's sometimes difficult to know what kind of answer to give. A beginner needs every detail spoon fed to them, while you can describe a solution in more general terms to an experienced programmer and let them fill in the details.