# No reason for being excluded from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban

As StackExchange becomes more frequently the official forum for popular open source software, if you are locked out your options for help are really limited.

Would it not be fair to have one programming forum for advanced and educated programmers and another for self educated newbies? As long as the latter were not trying to get "free rides" but actually working at solving their problems?

I have for a long time now, it seems, been unable to ask questions in the one forum most of my questions are directed at and I see user questions in there way below even my level of programming knowledge but allowed in , I guess because they don't ask so many questions!

Point is I cannot even find a way back in because there is no way. I would have to miraculously have users point score my questions up and I could be dead by the time that happens haha

I think there needs to be some kind of get out of jail free card!

UPDATE: I just as suggested went back to improve on my questions but all of them are up voted besides two which are just neutral. There doesn't seem any plausible reason why my account is rejected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Propose Newbie-Overflow site or section](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/propose-newbie-overflow-site-or-section); see also [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: I think my question two part- First about newbies and second personal- How can I get back in!? :D

Comment: There would be a difference between having a "Stack Overflow for newbies" and a "Stack Overflow for bad questions" though... Creating another site would not lower our quality standards on that site. So if you continued asking the same questions there, you'd just get blocked there too. Then what?

Comment: @cea Each part is covered by one of the links I gave you. ***Read them! That's what they're there for!***

Comment: HAVE READ THEM! No way back in unless had questions voted up. I cannot ask a question, plain and simple. I can answer a question but my level is not high enough especially if I can't ask anymore :P

Comment: I am having to become wiley like the fox to find other forums...like some kind of drug addict ha

Comment: and I should win some kind of prize for being marked down :E~~

Comment: **Stack Exchange is *NOT* a forum**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum I'd say it is a type of forum.

Comment: And "discussion" is the term accepted here for my input

Comment: Your creating it in **BOLD** does not make it any less so.

Comment: @cea, the foundation of this network of sites is built on *not being a forum*, in the sense of those noisy, cheerful, unsearchable places that we love/hate so much. It's kind of basic etiquette here: not.a.forum.

Comment: Yes but here we are allowed, dare I say invited by the very definition of the accepted term 'discussion' , to have one discussion about my inability or anybody else's inability to take part in Q&A related to programming within the StackExchange list of network user EXCHANGE.

Comment: Increasingly, however I think this is not a discussion but rather a competition which I am clearly the winner for which user can accrue the most votes!

Comment: Actually I'd like to thank everyone in this forum, as I like to call it, because only today discussing with one of my sons how I am planning on going back to Uni to study computer science. :) Then I won't need a place like this will I.

Comment: @cea and yet, still here you are... if you dislike how it is here, why stay?

Comment: because  i live it

Comment: i am forced to peer in on some windows but i try my hardest to understand how stuff works.i don't really know why- i was an actor never liked any of this stuff- its some late age prob OCD thing ha

Comment: ummm..... what?

Comment: live another 30 years and you'll get it\

Comment: ummm okay, enjoy yourself

Comment: Will do Mister Greek MytholOgy

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: This was a long time ago in the scheme of things.

Answer (score 6):

> and another for self educated newbies?

Another forum for newbies isn't necessary, and if we had it it would be full of noise. The overarching aim of Stack Overflow is to have high quality questions with high quality answers - this is its differentiator. Progamming can be both ridiculously simple and ridiculously easy to get wrong; Stack Overflow is doing members a favour by demanding quality with their question writing, hopefully that quality and attention to detail will flow through to their code.

Newbie questions are fine on Stack Overflow, there's no discrimination based on your newness. The key thing is to make sure your questions are programming related (for example *[How to publish RTSP to RTMP in red5 server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21597604/109702)* is more suited to SuperUser because it is a product configuration issue rather than programming).

> Point is I cannot even find a way back in because there is no way.

You don't explain what you mean by *"been unable to ask questions in the one forum most of my questions are directed at "*. I see one closed question, there may be deleted questions I cannot see on your profile. In case you have been question banned follow the links posted in the comments above - they tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: I don't mind having my questions guided for improvement and clarity but I can't go in there at all. I've been blocked. I have no options for rejoining unless I suddenly grew an Einstein brain and could answer questions and get marked up.

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: the Help center says you need to show improvement but if you cannot ask questions the only way to do that would be to answer questions.

Comment: If you can show me another way to rejoin I'd be more than happy to give you the answer. :)

Comment: @cea - you can still edit your old questions to improve them and they can then get some positive vites

Comment: Yes but I've moved on from those questions and they are irrelevant now or just too illogical even to myself. What I need to learn is not open my mouth before I am truly ready.

Comment: But I will say I am most definitely a programming enthusiast for good and for bad and life goes on regardless. :)

Comment: @John Palmer I will try later to clean up my questions , thanks.

Comment: @slugster Ok I have gone back to edit my own questions but all questions have been up voted except for one which I have now edited.

Comment: Maybe i should buy a hitman programmist to up vote me