# So what's this "tag wiki" thing?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I was browsing around the new [tag synonym proposal system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479) and when I browsed to the [.NET tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) I was greeted with an "edit tag wiki" link. So I edited it and created some text. Very cool.

So I have a few questions.

1. What is the requirement to be able to edit this tag wiki? I clearly can't do it on all tags, so I'm guessing there is some activity requirement within the tag space before you get the ability to edit the wiki.
2. What should the content be? I browsed around a little, but I couldn't find any other examples with any content. I just included some basic text for the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) one. "Questions relating to the Microsoft .NET framework" with a link to `http://www.microsoft.com/net/`.

Comment: +1 "What should the content be". I too have suddenly gained the power to edit some of these tag wiki thingies. Do we have any guidelines on the content? Apologies if we do and I'm just overlooking it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq/49723#49723):

   > Every tag has a tag info page eg: faq if you have more than 100 upvotes on non-wiki answers with that tag you are entitled to edit the wiki section.
2. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50783/planning-thread-for-per-tag-faq):

   > I suggest this question here as a collection point for such FAQ entries in the various tags

   I suspect the format and contents of these will evolve with time and necessity; [the SO Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/) started out as one big question...

   Personally, I see little need to stick to a fixed format for each tag; different subjects will require different sorts of information.

Comment: I'm sure different subjects will need different information, but we could still strive to have a house style to give them a similar layout (analogous to Wikipedia pages). E.g. perhaps a heading-style title that explains the tag in words, one paragraph explaining the tag, FAQ (i.e. SO questions on the tag that are well worth reading for everyone) and a section of useful external links.

Comment: I would love to have a style guide to follow.  I [slapped together the php tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=php&sort=info) last night, and will try to adapt it to styles others have stumbled upon later today as time allows.

Comment: @Charles: I think you did a pretty decent job on the php tag. I'm sure other PHP users will contribute to it over time as well. Don't get hung up on formatting or picking a fixed style just yet - different topics have different needs, and we've only just started writing these. If you see a layout or writing style you like on another tag, then copy it; otherwise, standard recommendations apply: try to be clear, stay concise, don't bore your readers.

Comment: that's the current plan.  However, having some level of consistency between similarly themed tags (i.e. programming languages) is probably going to be beneficial to the users.  While that can be achieved through, well, asynchronous wikidom, I feel that at least some level of organization would be a good thing.

Comment: @Charles: I suspect we'll hash out something eventually, but right now I feel it's just too new - I really want to avoid coming up with "wiki standards" that work for programming languages but are inappropriate for, say, libraries or OS APIs. After all, tags themselves impose a fairly strict organizational structure.