# Tag-wiki for CW-mandatory tags?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, tag-wiki

There are a few tags on SO which are widely treated as requiring community wiki. I'm thinking of [code-golf] in particular, but there is also [subjective] and ::shudder:: [fun]. If the "rule" is obeyed uniformly, then no one should every get the requisite 100 non-CW votes needed to earn tag-wiki editing privileges.

- Would it be useful for [all | any of | a few of] these tags to have tag-wiki pages?
- If so, what selection criteria should be used choose who writes them, or do we just expect the team and or moderators to handle it?

BTW-- [Subjective has a tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=subjective) presumably due to the historical lack of CW at the very beginning and a less than uniform feeling about making subjective queries CW.

Comment: i've read this three times and i'm not quite sure what you mean by "tag wiki". is this post suggesting that (for example) all new questions tagged [subjective] should be made CW automatically?

Comment: @Kip: New feature. Follow the "Subjective has a tag-wiki" link and/or see [So what’s this “tag wiki” thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57992/so-whats-this-tag-wiki-thing)

Comment: We should ask [@Sam Hocevar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/111461/sam-hocevar) to write the [code-golf] wiki — [he has a score of 173.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=code-golf&sort=stats&pagesize=30) :p

Comment: @KennyTM 173 sounds like a horrible score for golf.