# Create tag wiki for exisiting tag that has no tag wiki yet with reputation smaller than 1500

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, tag-wiki, rules

**feature-request**

- in order to understand the background of a question via a [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag)
- as a user of stackoverflow.com with low [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation)  (< 100)
- I want more initial [tagwikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-wiki) being created that provide a short definition what the tag means.

Possible scenarios:

- Lowering the [rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) to create a wiki for a tag. Currently 1500 reputation points are required. A "top 20 answerer" for a tag will rarely look at the definition for that tag.
- Somebody creating a new tag *must* provide a short definition for the tag.
- Discuss the tag-definition as a regular question with answers that can be regulary voted like other questions. If the vote count is high enough its text will become the wiki-tag.

Background:

A few minutes ago I stumbled over this question:
  [how-do-you-handle-adding-something-like-devise-authentication-in-bdd-stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323732/how-do-you-handle-adding-something-like-devise-authentication-in-bdd-stories)

It is tagged with [devise](/questions/tagged/devise).
When following the link, I got the info that there is no tag wiki for this tag.

I found out that that "devise" has something to do with Ruby's open-source project "cucumber" but there was no way to put this information into stackoverflow because 
I don't have enough reputation.

There are several tags with no tag wiki.

**See also:**

- [Can't help create new tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70277/cant-help-create-new-tag-wiki)
- [Tag-wiki for CW-mandatory tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58043/tag-wiki-for-cw-mandatory-tags)