# Auto-generation of a FAQ

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Some questions are repeatedly asked time and again and closed as dupes. I just found the *nth* "free stock market data" question.

It would be quite nice to have a "top 100 closed as dupe questions" page, ranked by # of questions that are closed as dupe and linked to the original question.

I bet that stock market question will be near the top. :-)

Comment: ... desperately wanting to close this as a dupe for the sake of irony

Comment: I made a dupe related suggestion recently, coming from a different angle but partly similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/per-tag-faq-for-finding-dupes-needed-wanted

Comment: After reading both requests, I think this could have potential as a 10k tool. I'm just not sure if it would be useful for such a huge site like Stack Overflow -- it would need to be a pretty long list.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26621/whats-the-most-repeated-question-on-stackoverflow @JonSeigel

Comment: I think, for the purpose of documenting common questions, the tag wiki should be the tool. The only problem is that this feature is so obscure not many people uses it.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Obscurity is a question of marketing - links to a FAQ could be splattered everywhere. @Jon: I'm primarily interested in the "top X" questions, because by definition those are the most frequently duped questions. Also, this wouldn't have to be a "10K tool", this could be an auto-generated page.

Comment: Needs to be [@YiJiang](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61960/parse-more-than-one-word-for-comment-reply-system "Though, making it a link might've invalidated the reply") for it to work, Paul.