# Extreme redundancy and duplication of questions and tags concerning hashchange

Tags: discussion, tags

Going through the questions about the javascript event "onhashchange", there have become an extreme amount of duplicated questions as well as extremely similar tags.

- [browser-state](/questions/tagged/browser-state) - regarding the browsers state (in regards to the fragment-identifier and use of the onhashchange event)
- [hashchange](/questions/tagged/hashchange) - regarding the onhashchange event
- [fragment-identifier](/questions/tagged/fragment-identifier) - regarding the url hash
- [browser-history](/questions/tagged/browser-history) - regarding the history within the browser (should not be hashchange or fragment-identifier related)
- [ajax-history](/questions/tagged/ajax-history) - regarding using the onhashchange event for ajax purposes (should really be: ajax+hashchange)
- [ajax-bookmark](/questions/tagged/ajax-bookmark) - exact duplicate of the ajax-history tag.

My Proposal is:

1. Killing [ajax-history](/questions/tagged/ajax-history), and [ajax-bookmark](/questions/tagged/ajax-bookmark) and use the [browser-state](/questions/tagged/browser-state) instead. **Completed**
2. Retagging any [fragment-identifier](/questions/tagged/fragment-identifier) questions that do not explicitly concern the URL hash  (and rather just to do with the browser state) to use the [browser-state](/questions/tagged/browser-state) tag instead.
3. Retagging any [hashchange](/questions/tagged/hashchange) questions that do not explicitly concern the onhashchange event (and rather just to do with the browser state) to use the [browser-state](/questions/tagged/browser-state) instead.
4. Retagging any [browser-history](/questions/tagged/browser-history) questions that concern the browser state to use the [browser-state](/questions/tagged/browser-state) instead.
5. Discovering a better way to inform users that their question has been asked a billion times, and prevent answers to these duplicated questions. (Related question: [What can be done about repetitive questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62258/what-can-be-done-about-repetitive-questions))

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62258/what-can-be-done-about-repetitive-questions