# Duplicate questions & new answers

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, new-answers

I know this is already discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8578/161534) but since it's come to an end, I wanted to bring it to attention again. What some people may have forgotten is that people who know the answer to a question are not likely to **look for it**. It has to be **brought to their attention**. I totally agree that in most circumstances closing duplicates is the right choice but there are times when it's wrong. Just as an example:
[How to constraint a generic to be of type enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8689217/279982)
[Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79126/279982)

In the first question I got 2 different answers (1 answer and 1 comment) which in my opinion are much better than solutions in the old questions. I think @JonSkeet for sure knew the answer to the question but it just hadn't come to his attention to answer it. So I think there should be a new option to questions:

Something like people could vote on to ask for new answers, and if a question got like 5 (or even less) votes then the question is  brought to front page like a newly asked question.
Now when a duplicate is closed people could also vote on the original question to ask for new answers if it's needed.

I think this is a better option than just closing a question.

Answer (score 3):

Your [generic constrained to enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689217/how-to-constraint-a-generic-to-be-of-type-enum) example is not a good one as it is definitely a duplicate, and Jon has probably answered a few hundred of these himself. I knew the answer to your question because I first learnt that from Jon's answers to these questions - they are there, somewhere. In any case, your feature request is yet another variant on the *[How](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88827/calling-the-attention-of-a-some-paticular-user-s-to-a-question) [do I](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) [get a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109636/allow-users-to-bring-a-question-to-another-users-attention) [certain user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101894/route-a-question-to-certain-user) [to look at](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71727/ask-a-question-and-notify-users-on-specific-users-list) [my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-so-member-or-members)* Notice the number of links there - that's just some of the times this has been asked.

The problem is not that you need Jon Skeet's eyeballs on your question, it's that it can be difficult to find the best question that yours is a dupe for. There could still be a dozen "original" questions that yours could be linked to; picking the one out of the haystack that is most satisfactory to you could be a hit and miss affair.

But wait, there's more... as has been noted in the past, duplicate questions can still produce good original answers. Where possible the new answer should be [merged with the original question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/), helping to build a [canonical answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116087/another-take-on-canonical-answers-add-a-canonical-vote), and ensuring that the answer is not lost when [duplicate questions get deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/is-it-ok-to-delete-vote-dupes-which-has-been-asked-a-lot).

Comment: Thanks for the canonical answer link. Also I think on some level you may have misunderstood me. I did not mean to bring question to attention of any particular user, what I meant is some way to bring an old question to front page so anyone could see it again.

Answer (score 0):

There already exists a feature to bring a question to the attention of somebody who can answer it.  On any unanswered question there is the following:

[image]

This allows a person to bring the question to the attention of another person whom they believe can answer it (and would be willing to do so).

Note, however, an important prerequisite... One has to ***know someone*** who can answer.  Stack Overflow has no interest in increasing the noise to its contributors.  This would, as has been pointed out many times, undoubtedly drive away the highest-quality contributors.  (If Jon's noise-to-signal ratio from Stack Overflow reached a point where it actually interfered with his professional or even personal life, I doubt he'd forsake that life for more rep.)

Comment: Thanks. Also I think on some level you may have misunderstood me. I did not mean to bring question to attention of any particular user, what I meant is some way to bring an old question to front page so anyone could see it again.