# Flag Frequently Asked Questions

Tags: feature-request

I've researched this a little bit on meta and there are some good ideas on how to handle FAQs, but I come across event delegation in jQuery every single visit I've ever had to Stack Overflow and it always results in the same comments/answer.

Instead of marking these questions as "duplicates", because some of the questions can be phrased very differently and they are very rarely marked as duplicates, can we have some functionality to flag a question as a "Frequently Asked Question"?

The user could then select one of the [Frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=frequent) questions from the relevant tag to link to. The OP gets their answer and it's quick for those who know what the answer is to flag the question as an FAQ.

edit: This illustrates my point quite well. Say I want to flag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980992/how-to-make-onclick-fire-on-a-generated-div/18981050#18981050) as a duplicate of an event delegation question:

**Step 1:** Try "event delegation"
[image: event delegation]
Even though the question is tagged only `jQuery`, it pulls back results for C#

**Step 2:** Try "jquery event delegation"
[image: event delegation]
Only 4 votes? Surely has to be something more popular than that?

**Step 3:** Try "jquery .on()"
[image: on]
Not even close.

**Step 4:** Give up

If I clicked on "Duplicate of a Frequently Asked Question", had the choice of the top 20 questions in the jQuery tag, it would be so much easier.

Comment: But if they get their answer in one of those FAQ questions.... it's a duplicate, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but my point is nobody ever flags it as such. Case in point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980992/how-to-make-onclick-fire-on-a-generated-div/18981050#18981050 - I think users would be more inclined to mark these questions as FAQs rather than exact "duplicates". Full disclosure, I didn't flag it as a duplicate because it happens *so often*, I wouldn't know which of the 1,999,999 answers to choose. Forcing me to choose from the top 20 questions in the frequent tab would be so much easier and quicklier :)

Comment: The mechanism to do that is... voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not suggesting that there isn't a method for this already, I'm suggesting that there may be a way of making it easier for the community to mark these as duplicates - terminology aside.

Comment: I think this is similar to [Another take on canonical answers: Add a "canonical" vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116087)

Comment: @perhapsPekka Very similar indeed, but even simpler I think - just a matter of offering different search options within the duplicate dialog. I eventually found a suitable duplicate by searching for "dynamic HTML event jquery".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with only 4 votes. If it's got an answer that answers the question, it answers the question, and it can be marked as a duplicate (although a question that's received more attention would probably be (slightly) better).

Comment: You show us a few screenshots, but nothing actually points to the question you **want** to mark it as a duplicate of, never mind concrete steps to get there (is it actually one of the top "frequent" questions?).

Comment: If there is a question with 50 votes (such as the question I eventually flagged it as a duplicate of), I am more inclined to take that one over one with 2 votes as 99 times out of 100 it's just one of these duplicates which nobody flags. Oh well, guess I'll just have to be more clever with the way I search for them

Comment: I've found this question [What can be done about repetitive questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62258/what-can-be-done-about-repetitive-questions) which covers what I'm trying to get at and puts it in a much more elegant manner! Ironically, this is now itself a repetitive question :)