# Nicknames highlighting

Tags: feature-request, highlighting

`@nickname` template has become a de facto standard here so what about highlighting (via JS) the `@current_nickname` in the questions, answers and comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@name is not a "standard de-facto", it's a [method of communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). It's also one that has [a lot of rules that people don't remember or never learn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64501/using-the-comment-pro-tip-increases-the-risk-of-not-getting-notified-about-resp/64503#64503). I see this highlighting as producing little more than noise.

It's only going to highlight things that you've already seen in the past, things that you are already alerted about by your recent activity envelope, and things that you would already notice because you are actively observing the question for new comments. This last point is the key one - all of the information provided by the highlight is rendered moot in any scenario when you can notice the highlight, because you'll already be reading the passage that contains it. This is disregarding all of the mess with changing display names or close-enough display names which make comment replies occasionally misdirected already.

I acknowledge that sometimes people do open a question only to skim through it, but I think the intersections in which those people will open a question that silently mentions them are far too few to warrant the implementation.

Comment: Talking about *skimming through* ...

Comment: @Ladybug I was expecting that.

Comment: anyway, it is a way to point to the nickname. Why would not highlight it?

Comment: @zerkms I think a more important question is "Why highlight it?".

Comment: To emphasize on the addressing fact.