# Highlight user names on comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, highlighting

I have read some user requesting auto-completion when typing a user name with the `@user` notation, but I'm missing something simpler. It's the fact of displaying those user names in comments highlighted.

I think this can be specially useful for detecting misspellings we made, which it's something fairly easy, considering "original" user-names and a little familiarization with some names from other countries.

Comment: @mdalolmo I like the feedback loop with misspelling a user name!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74979/provide-more-user-feedback-for-unsuccessful-comment-replies

Comment: Something along the veins of [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65333/nicknames-highlighting)? Yours seems to be more for the broad sense than just on the scope of the individual user, though.

Answer (score 2):

I like this solution just as much as the auto-completion.  They both would serve the purpose of helping you select the name of the user and keeping from adding a comment that has a misspelled name that goes undetected.

A reply to comment button might be an easier option.  Either as a link next to each comment or a control to the right or bottom of the comment box that allows you to select and paste a user name.

However, one thing you can do to help avoid this issue without a change to stack overflow is to type less of the user name.

If I was repying to you instead of typing @mdelolmo, I could just type @m and as long as there was not another user with a name that starts with m between you and I in the chain of comments then it will notify you.