# Can we have a reply-to-this-comment arrow to click on, please?

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let's make it easier to reply within comments!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments)

In the chat, I became quite fond of the littte arrow to the right of every chat message to reply to that message:
[image]
It automatically adds the name of the person I want to reply to, which saves me the hassle of manually copying it or face the danger of misspelling someone's name. *Can we have this for comments, please?*
(In the chat, the arrow also makes my message refer to a *specific* message of the other user, but I don't dare asking for that.)

Alternatively, the tab-completion as in chat would be great, too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72526/add-a-reply-button-next-to-comments), which was closed as a duplicate of [this more elaborate one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments). But to save you the trouble, this is pretty much an auto-declined request.

Comment: @AlEverett: And of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/add-reply-link-to-comment-that-pre-populates-comment-box-with-username and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments! How can I have missed those?

Comment: @Grace: This seems to be a much thought after feature. I suppose I'm missing an obvious reason why it is declined again and again?

Comment: It is pretty much sought after, but the decision against it is pretty solid. There's a good exchange between Jon Seigel and Jeff Atwood in some comments on a question, but I can't find it right now. Surmising from my memory of it, it's partly to avoid explicitly encouraging large back-and-forth discussion in comments through the UI.

Comment: I would really like to have tab completion. I don't really use that click interface.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I added tab-completion to the SE Modifications userscript [listed here](http://rchern.github.com/StackExchangeScripts/) a few weeks ago (though I need to fix some outstanding issues with it). Not as good as native support, but if you have the option of using userscripts, it might be good enough to tide you over for the moment at least.

Comment: @Johannes Actually, there's [already an active request for tab completion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please). As well, sbi, that link is where the discussion I mentioned happens to be.

Comment: oh thanks! I just installed the user script, but it doesn'T seem to work (I'm using chrome. "@<tab>" doesn't complete).

Comment: @Tim, oops forgot to @ you.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Hmm, it works alright for me. I'll double-check after work today and see what might be the issue, sorry about that!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb (This is very much after the fact, but...) I recently overhauled the auto-complete in [SE Modifications](http://stackapps.com/q/2138/4746) if you want to give it another go. I'm using Chrome 11 right now and it seems to work fairly reliably.