# Why does the reply arrow in chat point right?

Tags: discussion, chat

This is only minor but the reply arrow in chat points right ([see image here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/can-we-have-a-reply-to-this-comment-arrow-to-click-on-please)).

I would have expected it to point left, like the enter button and other replies, e.g. in Outlook.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow to initiate a reply goes down, then right.

This is to counter the arrow used on the replying message, which goes up, then left, shown below.

[image: Arrow'd]

Basically, it goes right to illustrate that "This is where I'm going to put my reply", with the right-directional arrow indicating thus "This is where my reply comes from". Grouping them together, you'd get a linking loop that symbolizes the connection between the reply and its origin message.

Comment: true, but it this does not explain why this is different to the rest of the world. Why not e.g. have an up arrow to go back to the "replying message".

Comment: @Wikis If it was an up arrow for the reply, then wouldn't the "reply arrow" have to be down to match it? They're designed as a pair, and due to how it operates, it is closer to how forum threads mark replies than how mail clients do it. In such nested threading, you use up (and sometimes left) to indicate the point towards the origin.

Comment: well, I have to admit that you *have* answered "why". But I think it is counter-intuitive and should be changed. But that's another question...