# Does @notification work for users with spaces in their user names?

Tags: discussion, notifications, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I'm told that when I add a comment to a thread and begin with the @username syntax, the username gets a notification, however, I wonder whether this still works when their name has a space in it as in @user name. I ask because this would seem to be ambiguous in the case that there is both a user named 'user name' and one named 'user' the following have an ambiguous target user for the notification:

```
@user name is the first word of my message to 'user'.
@user name My comment begins with 'My' to 'user name'.
```

If this works great, if not, is there a syntax to allow it such as @user_name. If there is an alternate syntax, how can this be made more discoverable?  If not, perhaps an enhancement is appropriate here.

Comment: For all the awesome inner workings of comment replies, please check out [our FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). To address your specific inquiry as detailed in there, if a user has a space then you simply truncate it. For example, to address me and not Gracefulness, you'd say @GraceNote or at least @Gracen.

Comment: Additionally, look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61960/allow-for-comment-reply-to-usernames-with-less-than-three-characters-in-first-wor

Comment: Voting to close because this is a dupe of the FAQ entry @Grace linked to, but also upvoting for the wording.