# Why am I not able to upvote, downvote, format, comment, etc. on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, caching, jquery

I am not able to upvote, downvote, format code or even insert comments on SO.

There is a JavaScript or jQuery error, I think.

Firefox's error console of says "$ is not defined."

Comment: Try force reloading the page using `ctrl` + `F5`

Comment: Alternatively, try defining $. (^_^)

Comment: @Yi: Great worked it solved many thanks. if someone post as answer so that I can accept

Comment: @Shakti Yi didn't see your notification, the minimum is 3 letters, so @YiJ should work - post new comment with this and he'll be notified.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, that particular problem is now `[status-completed]`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61960, so \o/

Comment: @Yi great news, thanks! :) (by the way \o/ is Orz spaceship! (http://www.sa-matra.net/sounds/starcontrol/orz.gif) ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this occurs, you need to force-refresh the page, which you can do using (depending on your browser...)

SHIFT + F5

CTRL + F5

or

APPLE + R for Safari on Mac!