# Is it OK to create a "Topic Wiki" from several related questions?

Tags: discussion, related-questions

There is a lot of confusion and contradicting information related to building landscape applications on the iPhone. All of the below questions relate to this issue:

- [Landscape only iPhone app with multiple nibs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891395/landscape-only-iphone-app-with-multiple-nibs)
- [Iphone Landscape mode switching to Portraite mode on loading new controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835989/iphone-landscape-mode-switching-to-portraite-mode-on-loading-new-controller)
- [iPhone Landscape-Only Utility-Template Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525737/iphone-landscape-only-utility-template-application)
- [iPhone: In landscape-only, after first addSubview, UITableViewController doesn't rotate properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632117/iphone-in-landscape-only-after-first-addsubview-uitableviewcontroller-doesnt)
- [Has anyone attempted and succeeded in getting Apple's iPhone PageControl demo to render correctly in Landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582063/has-anyone-attempted-and-succeeded-in-getting-apples-iphone-pagecontrol-demo-to)

However, none of these questions contains a 100% working/correct answer and only describes one aspect of the problem. Either the information is outdated (e.g. relates to SDK 2.0 where things have been different, current is 3.2), unreliable or there's just a 95% solution marked accepted. Some answers provided good hints to partially correct solutions, but have not received any upvotes. Some accepted answers can't even be considered a solution but are rather links to diffuse discussions in other communities.

In the spirit of SO as a place for high quality questions and answers this situation must somehow be resolved. I spent significant amount of time investigating this issue and found a solution that I hope is working 100% (as far as my testing showed) and does not require extensive manual procedures.

I want to write it down, however I'm wondering what is the most efficient/appreciated way to deal with this situation. I could either:

- Open up a CW Question (e.g. iPhone Landscape FAQ) gather all issues together and present the solution I have found
- Write a sample answer and copy/paste it to each question.

What should I do?

Comment: related question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq

Comment: @Juha: It's somewhat close to this, only it applies to every question tagged [iphone] and [landscape]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make a new question and answer, make the question community wiki. 
  Then add a comment/answer with a link to your question to each of the other questions so your question gets linked into *Linked* -panel.
- You could take also take an existing question and make it a more generic and answer that. This way you don't need to yet another dupe question.