# Feature Request: Link to Page of Related Links

Tags: feature-request

Hello All,

First, as an aside, this is my first meta question: if this would be better suited for a different meta, or is an inappropriate use, please let me know.

I am a regular user of Stack Overflow, and an active participant on Programmers.SE.  One thing I'm noticing is that there are a lot of repeat questions, particularly on Programmers.  There are also starting to be a bunch of "almost but not quite duplicate" questions.

I think that it might be worthwhile to have a repository for similar questions that can be pointed to in a new question.  Sometimes "closed as duplicate of..." isn't really enough, but it is annoying to cut and paste an answer from one question to another.  Conversely, it's a little annoying to when asking a question to see the same answer a number of times when you are looking for something slightly different.

It may be nice, then, to have a place to create a page that has links to similar questions, and be able to reference that in the new question.

**Edit: Additional Info**

I believe that a user would need a certain level of reputation to create and/or to add a link to such a page.  Perhaps it could even lead to a new badge or two.

Comment: Either Wonko the Sane is a very known reference that I don't know, or I might recognize you from a completely different net community. But to get off of that tangent, this is the proper Meta site to have asked this. ♪

Comment: @Grace Note: I guess I should have added "among others" on the list of sites I participate on... :)  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @GraceNote [Hitchhiker's Guide?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonko_the_Sane#Wonko_the_Sane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple means for doing this already exist.

The [tag wiki info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq/49723#49723) for a tag can be customized and filled out ([example on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/programming-languages/info)).  You could include links to questions here.  (See an example at the bottom of the [c# tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info).

Each tag also has an [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/programming-languages/faq) page which contains the most commonly linked questions in the tag.

Also note that the sidebar of every question lists related questions.