# Why not have a FAQ/how-to feature in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta-faq

I keep seeing these question about how to do this or that using this.

I was wondering if there could be a FAQ section where user can post a commonly asked question along with the answer so other users can quickly find answers to some basic questions and can vote if they found it useful.

**EDIT**

I guess I am  thinking of something more like a "how-to section" where some of the more experienced users can post question and answers on how to do certain tasks. More like a learning tool.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=faq&pagesize=50)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chichiray notes, the FAQ feature already exists, with topics selected automatically based on what gets linked to.

The facility for posting "how-to" docs also exists, after a fashion: [they have to be written in Q&A format](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/):

> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.

#### Ref:

- [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)
- [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)

Comment: **[tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/165773)** feature looks worth mentioning, too: "...a community-wiki editable home page per tag. One where we could place essentially the tag-specific FAQ..."

Answer (score 7):

Most commonly linked questions are already listed under the "faq" tab when you browse the main tag page. If it wasn't most commonly linked, then it wouldn't have been most commonly asked.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is the listing of the [java](/questions/tagged/java). Just click the "faq" tab in the top:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Lol I hadn't noticed that link till you and @Servy pointed it out. Please read my edit. What I had in mind is I guess more like a tutorial section where users can learn by looking at examples.

Comment: I'm unsure how that's in the end better than what Stack Overflow already offers as being a Q&A site.

Comment: Well I see a lot of questions that people don't know how to get started. Most of the question on SO are about specific issues people are having (and they should be) but if there are these tutorials people can follow I think there will be less of these vague question that get voted down all the time. These questions are usually asked by new users who might get discouraged if their question are in the negatives

Comment: Those people who can't figure where to start are then on SO simply at the wrong place. They're better off buying a starter book and/or reading the authoritative resource on the matter (e.g. Oracle's own tutorials in case of Java).

Comment: Yea maybe ... They don't have to be beginner level tutorials you could (should) have advance  stuff as well ....I don't know I just thought it would be neat to have place where you can learn new  things in a clean environment like SO.