# Is there a compilation of useful SO links?

Tags: support

Every so often someone (usually a high rep user) will post a link to a “definitive guide” that was constructed by the community. For example:

- [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/911182)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/911182)
- [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/549/911182)

I suspect there are many others like these.

Guides like those listed above are extremely useful, but I've been coming across them by chance. Is there a convenient list of these guides or “suggested reading list” somewhere? If not, may I suggest we create one and put the link somewhere that's easy to find. Since the FAQ has been replaced with "help" in the main menu, perhaps something like this would be an appropriate FAQ. (Questions that are *really* frequently asked.)

Comment: Short answer... no.  Questions like the ones you linked are not considered good questions for Stack Overflow anymore.  They are historically significant questions that are leftovers from when rules were more relaxed.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I understand the rules have changed, but I'm glad those questions are still around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PHP tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) includes many frequently asked questions, as well as other useful links related to PHP.

*Other tags also have their own tag-wikis, see this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq).*

Comment: Yes, and Tag Wikis are the place where such links should go.

Comment: Hmm. Been here for nearly 2 years and did not see that. :p That's exactly what I was looking for. So I can just edit that if I come across a link that isn't in there, like the third one in my list?

Comment: @Herbert yep, there is a review queue for adding stuff, so do add things if you think they are a good fit.